# What data is available in client machine

Tags: hadoop

I know that the client machine consult the name node to store the data it contains.

Also the client machine will have Hadoop installed in it with cluster settings.

What cluster settings are present ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an HDFS command is invoked, the Client has to send a request to the `Namenode` and to do so `fs.defaultFS` property is required. Similarly when submitting a YARN job, it needs `yarn.resourcemanager.address` to connect with the `ResourceManager`.

File level HDFS properties like `dfs.blocksize`, `dfs.replication` are determined at the Client node. If they need to be changed from their default, add the respective properties at the Client node.

Normally, the same set of configuration properties (`*-site.xml` files) defined in the nodes of the Cluster would be defined in the Client node as well. Having a uniform cluster settings among all the nodes of the Cluster inclusive of the Client nodes is considered the best practice.

Comment: Where are the cluster nodes needs to be present? Same as that of name node or data node?

Comment: you mean client nodes? They can be any node that has hadoop installed and have access to the cluster (i.e., master and slaves). That makes the master node and slave nodes also eligible to take the role of a client node. In some env, the client nodes will be dedicated nodes that do not run any instances of hadoop daemons.

Comment: a)  If client node is dedicated and does not run any instance of hadoop deamons then what role will client node have in spite of hadoop being installed on them? b)Does the master and slave mean the Name node and the Data node respectively?

Comment: a) it will be used only to submit jobs and invoke filesystem operations b) yes (can be resourcemanager and nodemanager too)